# Thunderbird: change color in compose window

Tags: colors, firefox, thunderbird

I know Thunderbird UI is highly customizable through `UserChrome.css`.

For example, changing the color of the window bar can be done easily:

```
menubar, toolbar, nav-bar, #TabsToolbar > *{
  background-color: rgb(245,199,18) !important;
}
```

But where can I find the names of the elements that I want to change ?

For example, in the compose window, newer Thunderbird colors the whole header, the header itself and the input filed (everything is light grey).

[image]

Whereas, the older Thunderbird only colored the header, and left the user input field distinctly different:

(ignore the differences in color themes, ie light vs dark).
The point is the distinct differentiation between the heading (ie From, To), and the actual email address typed by the user.

How can I find the name of the element, and change the color using `UserChrome.css` ?

I am using `Thunderbird 68.3` on `Debian Buster`

[image]

Comment: i explained how and what on my answer, (i have to go) i'll add later on a solution with what you need to use in your `UserChrome.css` if you did not succeed to achieve it meanwhile ;)

Comment: @intika - solution using `UserChrome.css` would be better, because it would persist when `Thunderbird` is upgraded.

Comment: yes sure, i agree, i just explained the whole thing in a dev perspective :) i am looking toward the proper code for `UserChrome.css`

Comment: i added a quick answer for the `UserChrome.css` needed code :)

Comment: i edited the answer for a more suitable code ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved on `UserChrome.css` with

```
#msgSubject {
  background-color: -moz-field !important;
}

#msgIdentity {
  background-color: -moz-field !important;
}

.textbox-addressingWidget {
  background-color: -moz-field !important;
}

.dummy-row {
  background-color: -moz-field !important;
}
```

Or the alternative below... you can replace `var(--lwt-toolbarbutton-active-background, rgba(255, 255, 255, .4))` with the color you want (like red, blue, etc) for the dummy box at the left of the fields (cc, bcc etc.)

```
#msgSubject {
  background-color: -moz-field !important;
}

#msgIdentity {
  background-color: -moz-field !important;
}

.textbox-addressingWidget,
.dummy-row:not(:first-child) {
  background-color: -moz-field !important;
}

.addressingWidgetCell:first-child, 
.dummy-row-cell:first-child {
  background-color: var(--lwt-toolbarbutton-active-background, rgba(255, 255, 255, .4)) !important;
}
```

**Thunderbird v68.3.0 and v68.3.1:**

Note that in a brand new installation you will need to unlock custom CSS usage with:

```
Settings/Options > Advanced > General > Config Editor...
toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets > true
```

Then create a folder named `chrome` under the profile directory, then create the file `userChrome.css` (those are case sensitive)

Here is an updated css for TB v68.3.x using the color #e06d30...

```
#msgSubject {
  background-color: -moz-field !important;
}

#msgIdentity {
  background-color: -moz-field !important;
}

.textbox-addressingWidget,
.dummy-row:not(:first-child) {
  background-color: -moz-field !important;
}

.addressingWidgetCell:first-child, 
.dummy-row-cell:first-child {
  background-color: #e06d30 !important;
}

.addressingWidgetCell:nth-child(2), 
.dummy-row-cell:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #e06d30 !important;
}
```

Comment: the first solution is almost perfect, but there is one problem which I was not able to solve. The other 2 address lines have the heading colro removed as well: screenshot here:  https://ibb.co/k4qRzC8

Comment: @MartinVegter yes i know this is why i posted the second solution which let you chose the color of the heading, you can for instance use the second solution with the color #be4b0e (captured from your screenshot) like so `background-color: #be4b0e !important;` i'll update the answer with the full code as example

Comment: here is how it looks like. solution 2: https://ibb.co/G90GXwH, and example: https://ibb.co/Lzg8D24

Comment: - also, after changing `UserChrome.css`, is there a way to reload Thunderbird, so that I don't have to restart each time ?

Comment: i was testing in thunderbird v60 i guess that they changed the headers dumy box on thunderbird v68... i will do some test and update the answer ;)... for the `UserChrome.css` reload, there is no simple/efficient way to do this without restart... the post here explain how to achieve it, but sometime this does not work https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1409065

Comment: @MartinVegter i just updated the answer with a new code that should fit your needs ;)... if you change the theme you will need to update the color #e06d30

Comment: thank you. Everything works perfectly now.

Answer (score 2):

For Thunderbird and Firefox, sources that are edited with `UserChrome.css` are available on `/install-dir/omni.ja` this file is a zipped directory (without compression) containing all the sources (javascript, xul, css etc.) of the displayed windows...

To edit/view the sources directly you can do

```
mkdir tmp; cd tmp;
cp ../location-of-install-dir/omni.ja .
unzip omni.ja
```

Edit what you want and/or get the value that you are looking for, then you can rebuild the file with

```
rm omni.ja #(remove the copied one)
zip -qr0XD omni.ja *
```

The file you are looking for is `./chrome/messenger/content/messenger/messengercompose/messengercompose.xul` with its included css and xul indicated at the beginning of the file, like `chrome://messenger/content/bindings.css` and `chrome://messenger/skin/messengercompose/messengercompose.css` etc.

Chrome:// addresses permit to access files located on the omni.ja, extensions files, etc... those urls can be browsed with Thunderbird directly if you have extension like [this](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/open-tab/?src=search) or [this](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/thundertabs/?src=search) unfortunately they are not yet updated to v68

Usually to identify element that you want to edit you can use the debugger (Ctrl+Shift+I) available under the menu: Tools > Developer Tools > Developer Toolbox, then use the dom object inspector top left button, but make sure to select the proper window first with the drop-down menu on the top-right (for instance `messengercompose.xul` for the new message window, it will be listed there if you opened a compose window).

Extension like [Dom Inspector](https://addons.thunderbird.net/fr/thunderbird/addon/dom-inspector-dm/?src=search) can be helpful here, but it is not yet compatible with v68