# remove the remote content warning in thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, privacy

Thunderbird [pats itself on the back](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/remote-content-in-messages) for not loading external content and protecting your privacy, but at the same time has a bright yellow notification bar tempting you constantly to do exactly that:

[image]

There is a description of how to make that notification bar go away in Windows [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1273397). They want you to create a file called **userChrome.css** and add the following to it:

```
#mail-notification-top{
display: none;
}
```

I'm using Thunderbird 78 and Debian 10 and did a `find` search in my user folder and found `.themes/CBlue/cinnamon/userChrome.css` and added that css to it, saved and rebooted, but the notification in thunderbird is still there. Any ideas how to make it go away?

Comment: You could at the very least translate the german line.

Comment: Why? The point is well made

Comment: Cardamom, you've edited the CSS for Cinnamon. Probably worth reverting that change

Comment: _To protect your privacy, Thunderbird has blocked remote content in this message_ is the message they have in the English version. @roaima thanks, have changed Cinnamon back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Linux, `userChrome.css` needs to be created in `~/.thunderbird/blahblah.default/chrome`, where `blahblah.default` is replaced with the name of your actual profile folder in `~/.thunderbird`.

Just tried it on my install, and it works as expected.

Comment: Thanks, have voted up, are you on Thunderbird 78? Is that the only thing in your userChrome.css or is there some kind of namespace thing? This is now turning into a real pain.. There seems to be more to it, like the css no longer loads automatically, at the bottom of [this page](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1298376) there is an answer which says that in Thunderbird 78 you need to tell it somehow to load userChrome.css ! I just spent about half an hour trying.. Some other links about this - [1](https://github.com/Aris-t2/CustomCSSforTb)

Comment: [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/559960/thunderbird-change-color-in-compose-window), My exact version number is 78.10.0 Say if anyone knows how to make that css file load

Comment: I'm running 78.8.1 (64-bit). My original test was with a bunch of other stuff in the css file. I just tried userChrome.css empty except for your bit of css, and it worked as well. You probably did this, but just to make sure... Did you close TB and restart it after adding or changing userChrome.css? Because that's necessary for TB to apply the changes.

Comment: If that isn't it, this might be... Check TB's Config Editor for `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` and set it to `true` if necessary (mine's set to `true`; switching it to `false` and restarting TB disables css). If you have to set it, you'll probably need to restart TB for the css to be applied. Suggested by [this page about Firefox](https://www.ghacks.net/2019/05/24/firefox-69-userchrome-css-and-usercontent-css-disabled-by-default/).

Comment: That _was_ it but you have to chnge `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` in TB not in firefox. Thanks so much for testing these things! It looks beautiful now, that should be standard without that stupid yellow banner. That was quite convoluted to get rid of it.. Went to 'settings' (_not_ 'folder settings' or 'account settings') and scrolled to the bottom, selected 'edit configuration' and accepted the warning.